# MIPS program is Not working Error: Symbol exit not found in the table

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.text
main:
```

check whether the second value that user entered is less than zero and if yes the exit the program

```
blez $t1, exit
```

Taking the first input from the user

```
la,$a0,InputValone
li,$v0,4
syscall

li,$v0,5
move $t0,$v0
syscall
```

Taking the second input from the user

```
la,$a0,InputValTwo
li $v0,4
syscall

li $v0,5
move $v0,$t1
syscall
```

multiply the two inputs

```
mul $t2,$t1,$t0
move $t3,$t0

loop:
    beq $t2,$t3, endloop    #if $t2==$t3, end the program
    add $t3,$t3,$t0     #else $t3=$t3+$t0

    b loop

    la      $a0,OutputValue
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    move    $a0,$t3
    li      $v0,1
    syscall


    endloop:
.data
    InputValone: .asciiz "Enter Your First Value : "
    InputValTwo: .asciiz "Enter Your Second Value : "
    OutputValue: .asciiz "Output is : "
```

Comment: You need to add a label "exit:" somewhere in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>  endloop:
>  .data
> ```

You do not really want to do this??

Using a jump instruction like `blez $t1, exit` or `beq $t2,$t3, endloop` you jump to a label.

Obviously the `exit:` label is missing.

And it is not defined which instruction follows the `endloop:` label:

Normal compilers (for real MIPS CPUs, not for MIPS emulators) would insert some dummy bytes between the last instruction of the code section and the `.data` section - just like that:

```
endloop:
  .word some_dummy_data
  .word some_dummy_data
  .word some_dummy_data
  .word some_dummy_data
  .word some_dummy_data
  ...
.data
```

The CPU would interpret that bytes as instructions and execute them...

You'll have to add the `exit:` label and you`ll have to add code after the`endloop:` label:

```
exit:
endloop:
    li      $v0,<value that exits the program>
    syscall
```

Not knowing your simulator I cannot tell you the correct value for `v0` for exiting the program. For Linux/MIPS a value of `v0=4001` would be suitable...